# Добавление контента на японском в БД

Tags: кодировка

Есть сайт PHP/MySQL.

При добавлении контента через админку на японском языке контент добавляется некорректно: вместо японских иероглифов - одни знаки *?*.

Английский и русский текст добавляется без проблем. Также в статических файлах (*.php*, *.html*) японский добавляется и отображается без проблем.

В *.htaccess* есть:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

В `header`-е есть:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Что надо сделать, чтобы японский отображался корректно?

Comment: Какой коллейшен стоит в бд? Насколько помню, utf-8 "по умолчанию" был урезанным и нужно было ставить utf8mb4.

Comment: Экранирование тоже дб с учётом кодировки (real_escape_string), также как и параметры соединения с БД (везде utf8).

Comment: Кодировка стоит utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

Comment: А как посмотреть какое *Экранирование* и параметры соединения? Кодировка сервера: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы использовать Японские символы (иероглифы) в БД MySql, надо использовать расширенную таблицу символов:

- **[UTF-8](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)** (**utf8mb4**) [использует 1 - 4 байт]
- **[UTF-16](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)**     [использует 2 или 4 байта.]
- **[UTF-32](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32)**   [используют  фиксировано 4 байта]  (Не ваш случай..  вы скорее всего используете php и html5, а стандарт HTML5 гласит, что «авторы не должны использовать UTF-32, поскольку алгоритмы определения кодировки, описанные в данной спецификации, не отличают его от UTF-16».)

---

Вам идеально подойдет UTF-16!

Здесь можно попробовать найти  [диапазон японских иероглифов в UTF-16](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B,_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D0%AE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5)

---

**Символы кодовой таблицы UTF-8 (utf8mb4), UTF16, UTF32 доступны в MySQL 5.5 и выше.**

(подробнее в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/charset-unicode-sets.html) MySql)

---

Если у вас MySQL 5.5 и выше, то можно выполнить следующие действия:

1) **Сменить кодировку для таблицы БД**, в которой вы собираетесь хранить такие символы

2) В коде HTML страницы добавить:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-16">
```

или средствами php:

```
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-16')
```

3) Сменить кодировку для чтения символов для запросов при помощи PHP:

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf16 COLLATE utf16_general_ci');
```

Comment: Автор отписал, что у него и так используется полноценный UTF-8. UTF-16 нет смысла использовать из-за функционала, идентичного UTF-8, вкупе с повышенным потреблением байт.

Comment: Я предлагаю, автору решение... Воспользуется он им, или нет - ему решать. Про размер символов я в своем ответе уточнил сразу:" UTF-16  [использует 2 или 4 байта.]"... Я тоже сталкивался с подобной проблемой (китайские иероглифы) и мне это помогло... Я лишь делюсь своим решением... + автор не написал, что для него критичен размер символов... и ссылку на офф.сайт с документацией MySql я не просто так привел(там иногда много полезного пишут).  @Etki предложите автору свои варианты решения... Мне  интересно. Буду рад  посмотреть на вашу альтернативу...

Comment: автор написал, что у него используется utf8mb4

Comment: Умиляют люди, которые минусуют не предлагая своих вариантов )))